# curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host

Tags: curl

I have a curl command like below:

```
curl 'http://airtel-bd.com/smshttpquery/qs?REQUESTTYPE=SMSSubmitReq&USERNAME=alrm&PASSWORD=alrm&MOBILENO=01939900347&MESSAGE=Todays+Task:%0ATask_Name:+'$task'0AScheduled_Time:+'$time1'&TYPE=25&ORIGIN_ADDR=MS-BD-Task'
```

Here,

```
time=10:40
Task= Monthly dashboard report.
```

but I am getting below error during run the command. I think space is the issue in Task value.

> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'dashboard'
>
> curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'report'

Comment: Any one please can you help me how i can solve the space isssue in curl to send sms........Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Try replace space with `+` or `%20`.

See [URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information.

Comment: thanks for reply. But problem is that i am taking the value from Database in a variable. So how can i use + or %20. Please help me.

Comment: Doing string replacement will be fine

Comment: You should tell us which language you're using, and some additional information. Check out http://SSCCE.org